# MS Access filter and show data from selected time period

Tags: sql, vba, database, date, ms-access

I have a table into which I put dates how long a machine was out of order. Example:

| id | Machine | Start date | End date | Number of days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 10.02.2020 | 17.02.2020 | 07 |
| 2 | 1 | 03.04.2020 | 09.04.2020 | 06 |
| 3 | 2 | 25.10.2020 | 06.11.2020 | 12 |
| 4 | 3 | 28.11.2020 | 10.12.2020 | 12 |

Machine number corresponds to an ID in appropriate Machine's table.

For start I would like to have a query or form where I would select a machine from combo box and time period (date picker or type it) and it would return how many days the machine was out of order during that time.

So, if I select machine with ID 3 and time period from 01.01.2020 to 31.12.2020 it would show 19 days. If I select for example machine with ID 2 and time period from 01.11.2020 to 30.11.2020 it would return 6 days and so on.

How would you go about this in Access? I am new to Access and VBA.

Comment: I think you meant Machine 2 would show 11 days or you meant Machine 1 would show 6 days. Not the ID values but the Machine values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your answer, I'll give it a go. I meant machine 2, as it was out of order in selected time period only for 6 days (from 01.11.2020 to 06.11.2020). If I selected time period before 25.10.2020 it would be 11 days.

Comment: Suggestion in answer will retrieve records that fall within the date range and sum the Number of Days values. It will not adjust for partial overlap. That would require much more elaborate code. Machine 2 record will not meet criteria and expression returns 0. I deleted answer as it does not satisfy requirements.

Comment: And Machine 2 (record 3) has 12 days. None of these Number of Days counts include the first (or the last, whichever way you want to look at) day of range. Is that what you want?

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to produce desired output. Place function in a general module.

```
Function GetDaysDown(dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date, intMac As Integer)
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, intDays As Integer, dteDate As Date
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Data WHERE Machine = " & intMac & _
                                 " AND (StartDate BETWEEN #" & dteStart & "# AND #" & dteEnd & _
                                 " # OR EndDate BETWEEN #" & dteStart & "# AND #" & dteEnd & "#)")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    dteDate = rs!startDate
    Do While dteDate < rs!EndDate And dteDate < dteEnd
        If dteDate >= dteStart And dteDate <= dteEnd Then
            intDays = intDays + 1
            'Debug.Print dteDate
        End If
        dteDate = dteDate + 1
    Loop
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
GetDaysDown = intDays
End Function
```

Call function from a textbox like:
`=GetDaysDown([tbxStart], [tbxEnd], [cbxMac])`

For more info about using international date format, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: This could be a German environment, where dates must be passed as formatted string expressions: `[Start Date] >= #" & Format([tbxStart], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#` .

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I am trying to run the function in textbox but it returns #NAME?. My field names seem to be correct and the form source is the the correct table. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put function in a general module named different from the function? They cannot have same name. Or is function behind the form?

Comment: When I run it today the function seems to run but I am getting runtime error 3075 - Syntax error in date in query expression "Machine = 110 AND (StartDate BETWEEN #01.11.2021# AND #11.11.2021# OR EndDate BETWEEN #01.11.2021# AND #11.11.2021#". Is this related to the date formats?

Comment: Probably. Why are you using period instead of slash? Did you try Gustav's suggestion and review the Allen Browne article?

Comment: I formatted it - this time correctly - according to Gustav but now I am getting data type mismatch error.

Comment: Change the declaration from `AS Date` to `AS String` because Format() results in a string, not a date.

Comment: That didn't work. I also tried changing my system regional format to US but still getting data type mismatch.

Comment: The function works for but I am in the U.S. using data in standard date structure. I've never had to program for international date so can't really help with that.

Comment: I came back to the issue and while I managed to make the function work it does not deliver correct results. It works when selected range does not go outside of the range when was the machine out of order but when the out of order range is within the selected range the function adds extra day for each loop (presumably). So if I select 10.01.2020 and 18.02.2020 the result should be 7 but it returns 8. Any ideas how to correct this? Thank you

Comment: Nevermind, deleting the equal operators in the Do While condition did the trick. If you edit your answer I mark it as the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Deleted the 2 equal signs from Do While line.